# What is the difference between hybris order management and fulfilment extensions? which one should be used when?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am working on customization of some order flows in Hybris and want to know what is exact difference between order management and fulfillment modules in Hybris. Also, when should we use which one of the above? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order management is part of a module you have to pay for (OMS). It contains a lot of workflows and frontends to handle orders after they have been created.

The fulfillment extension is part of the accelerator module and just adds the most basic processes to handle an order. When you need more than that, you will have to implement yourself.

I would suggest you make yourself familiar with the OMS module. If that fits your needs and your company wants to pay for it, you can use it.

Comment: I think there is more than one module which deals with order management. I don't remember how it is called and how they differ.

Comment: Thanks @Johannes. can you provide one example what is available in order management module and not in fulfilment ? Because fulfilment also has all basic flows of cancel order etc. why someone will need ordermanagement ?

Comment: If I recall correctly, the fulfillment extensions provide you a process what happens with an order after it was placed. That covers splitting the order into consignments and caring about sending those to the customer or letting the customer pick it up. However you cannot trigger an update to that order. E.g. you cannot mark orders as delivered and make sure the process continues with the next step that might be sending a mail to the customer that the order has been delivered.

Answer (score 0):

When you say Order management it covers order fulfillment already.

There are two things

1. Standard SAP Commerce order management
2. Order Management Services (OMS) - this comes with a different license

For SAP Commerce order management, there are extensions like saporderexchange, ysaporderfulfillment etc

For OMS, there are extensions like ysapomsfulfillment, saporderexchangeoms etc

[Refer this](https://help.sap.com/viewer/50c996852b32456c96d3161a95544cdb/6.1.0.0/en-US/8bc094c9866910149f04f703a4a54213.html?q=ysaporderfulfillment) for more details